# How can I optimize this "sort"?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, linked-list, nested-loops

So I am writing an algorithm which receives an array of sorted strings, and fills an array of singly user defined linked lists with the strings. Each linked list is a list of anagrams. For example, a list may contain "car", and "arc", because the both contain the letters a, c, and r.

Each header of the array must be in alphabetical order of the original list. So basically, if I had the input {"arc", "bed", "car", "deb", "xylophone"}, I would get the output:

arc, car

bed, deb

xylophone

How I achieve this is by using a nested for loop. The outer loop takes the i'th element, or "key" of the list and the inner loop takes the j'th element of the linked list array. If the  header of the j'th list holds null, immediately place the key into j and break. If the header does not hold null and if the key is an anagram of the header, it is added to the list. My linked list auto sorts.

Now this works very well for small inputs. But for very large inputs, say for n = 15000, it took upwards to 2 and a half minutes to finish the nested loops, and this takes too long. I don't think this has anything to do with my LinkedList methods, as there are no nested loops in it. Is there anyway I can really optimize this? Preferably, something better than O(n^2). Maybe breaking the input array into two and doing recursive calls?

```
//receives a lexicographically sorted string array called "input"
//some other code
//"sortAlphabetical(String)" is a sorting algorithm which lexicographically sorts a string. Used to compare two strings, uses a quick sort and is very fast... doesn't appear to be the issue.


        ArrayList<LinkedList> theList = new ArrayList<>();  //creates new linked lists for elements of the arraylist
        for(int k = 0; k < input.length; k++) {
            theList.add(new LinkedList());
        }
        int numberOfLists = 0;                      //tracks the number of non empty lists created, not relevant
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();         //begin tracking time
        for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            String theKey = input[i];
            for(int j = 0; j < theList.size(); j++) {

                if(theList.get(j).getHeadM() != null) {

                    if(sortAlphabetical(theList.get(j).getHeadM()).equals(sortAlphabetical(theKey))) {
                        theList.get(j).add(theKey);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if(theList.get(j).getHeadM() == null){

                    theList.get(j).add(theKey);
                    numberOfLists++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        elapsed = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        System.out.println("The nested for loops in sortList ran. It took " + elapsed + " nanoseconds.");
//more code
```

and I get the following output:

```
The nested for loops in sortList ran. It took 117061964600 nanoseconds.
```

Which is roughly 120 seconds, or two minutes. Any help or suggestions will be appreciated. If I need to add more information, let me know.

**edit:** Im not allowed to use Java library sorts such as hashsets, etc.

Comment: I think the way you will optimize this is to find a different algorithm. You aren't really sorting here from what I can see. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Note that words like "receives a lexicographically sorted string array called "input"" can be conveyed directly with code. Something like `void sortList(List<String> input)` or whatever the actual signature is already tells us a lot. Of course a comment that you assume the input list is already sorted will help clarify, too.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yeah that's why I put sort in quotations, because I don't really know what to call this. Im "sorting" the list of LinkedLists according to the requirements I stated. I want to get a better run time, because 2 minutes seems way too long, even for 15000 characters. I want help finding a better way to achieve the same effect that my nested for loops do, but without using nested loops as they give O(n^2) running time.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by *each header of the array must be in alphabetical order of the original list*. It needs to be **either** in *alphabetical order* **OR** *original order*. Your example input is unfortunate, because it does not distinguish this point. For example, what would be the output if the input was `{"car", "bed", "xylophone", "arc", "deb"}`?

Comment: @Bohemian As i mentioned, the original list is sorted into alphabetical order. Let's say we printed out the array of linked list line by line. The first word of each "line" is the header of each list, and the line consists of all words from the original list which is an anagram of the header. The headers, or each "first word" of every line must be in alphabetical order, when looking from top to bottom. Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: @user12192927 no, it is still unclear. Either the requirement is that output order is the same as input order, *or* output order is alphabetical. If you are saying that input order is guaranteed to in alphabetical order, then that problem can be more simply stated as "output must be same as input order", which *doesn't require sorting*. So, is input **guaranteed** to be alphabetically sorted? (The answer to that querstion it is significant to the time complexity of the optinal solution)

Comment: @Bohemian yes, input is guaranteed to be in alphabetical order, so output is the same as input order. It is sorted beforehand. I know my question isn't truly sorting, but I didn't really know what to call it, hence the quotation marks around sort.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
String theKey = input[i];
for(int j = 0; j < theList.size(); j++) {
```

You can get better performance in your for loops by factoring out the need of getting the right side of the condition expressions.

```
int inputLength = input.length;
int theListSize = theList.size();
for(int i = 0; i < inputLength; i++) {
String theKey = input[i];
for(int j = 0; j < theListSize; j++) {
```

This will save a method call every iteration when checking the condition.